# Java: Append Value to Property Key

Tags: java, file, io

I am using java.util.Properties to store properties in a file. I am able to store key/value pair successfully using the following code:

```
public String setKeyValue(String dir, String key, String value) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    File file = new File(dir);


    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(in);
    in.close();

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    properties.setProperty(key, value);
    properties.store(out, null);
    out.close();

    String myValue = (String) properties.getProperty(key);
    System.out.println (myValue);
    return myValue;
}
```

However, I am interested in updating (not replacing) a previous property so I can later retrieve them as an array.

For example my current property looks something like this:

```
email=email1
```

I want to change it to

```
email=email1, email2 //(this will be a continuous process of adding more emails)
```

This way I can later retrieve them as follows:

```
String[] emailList = properties.getProperty("email").split(",");
```

If you use the previous code it simply replaces the property. I need to append additional "value" to key..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most simple way would be do this...

```
String oldValue = properties.getProperty( key );
String newValue = "bla something";
String toStore = oldValue != null ? oldValue + "," + newValue : newValue;
properties.setProperty( key, value );
```

Of course, that's not very elegant, so I personally would probably extend my own `AppenderProperties` class from `Properties` and then add an `append` method. This would also be a good place to put all the array-related methods, so that you can remove specific values from your keys, etc.